# Write a program in mathematica whith Givens rotation

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

How can I write a program which can solve a system of linear equations with Givens rotation in mathematica .

Code attempt:

```
ar = CoefficientArrays[
   {x + y + z == 2, 3 x - 2 y + z == 4, x - y + 5 z == 6},
   {x, y, z}];

an = Normal[ar];
b = an[[2]];
n = Length[b];
Do[Do[a[i, j] = b[[i]][[j]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}];
r1 = (a[1, 1]^2 + a[1, 2]^2)^(1/2);
c = a[1, 1]/r1;
s = a[1, 2]/r1;
```

Comment: Try writing some code and if you are stuck, then ask for the help here.

Comment: I don't know how to start it ?! I write just this lines

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

Following your code.

```
{r1, c, s}
```

> {Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}

```
{a, b} = LinearSolve[{{c, -s}, {s, c}}, {r1, 0}]
```

> {1, -1}

[algorithm from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation#Stable_calculation)

```
GivensRotation[a_, b_] := Which[
   b == 0, c = Sign[a]; s = 0; r = Abs[a],
   a == 0, c = 0; s = -Sign[b]; r = Abs[b],
  Abs[a] > Abs[b],
  t = b/a; u = Sign[a]*Abs[Sqrt[1 + t*t]];
  c = 1/u; s = -c*t; r = a*u,
  True,
  t = a/b;
  u = Sign[b]*Abs[Sqrt[1 + t*t]];
  s = -1/u; c = -s*t; r = b*u
  ]

GivensRotation[a, b];

{r, c, s}
```

> {Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}

**Edit**

I'm not familiar with solving with Givens rotation.  Here are other methods for solving the simultaneous equations, just for interest.

```
Solve[{
  x + y + z == 2,
  3 x - 2 y + z == 4,
  x - y + 5 z == 6},
 {x, y, z}]
```

> {{x -> 1, y -> 0, z -> 1}}

also

```
LinearSolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {3, -2, 1}, {1, -1, 5}}, {2, 4, 6}]
```

> {1, 0, 1}

or

```
Inverse[{{1, 1, 1}, {3, -2, 1}, {1, -1, 5}}].{2, 4, 6}
```

> {1, 0, 1}

Comment: Excuse me I don't understand! This code is just for one column ?can this code solve system of linear equations ?

Comment: @user7677971 Yes, I'm not familiar with Givens rotation.  I would also be interested to know how it is applied.

Comment: If I introduce a book can you read this subject from that book?